# С++ Написать функцию, которая считает сумму символьных строк (char)!

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, циклы, char

Задание: Написать функцию на языке C++, которая считает сумму чисел, когда пользователь вводит их с клавиатуры. Например, пользователь вводит число 12, а затем 32, функция делает подсчет и после вызова функции на экран выводится ответ = 44.

Числа, которые пользователь вводит с клавиатуры заносятся в массивы с типом char, полученный результат после подсчетов в функции также должен быть занесен в массив типа char.

Я написала функцию, которая выполняет все эти действия, вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

const int n = 100;

void summ(char* a, char* b, char* c) {
   int a_len = strlen(a), b_len = strlen(b);
   int a_tmp = a_len - 1, b_tmp = b_len - 1, tmp, r = 0, digit;

   for (int i = 0; i < max(a_len, b_len) + 1; ++i) {


    tmp = ((a[a_tmp] - '0') + (b[b_tmp] - '0')) + r;
    if (b_tmp < 0)
        tmp = (a[a_tmp] - '0') + r;
    if (a_tmp < 0)
        tmp = (b[b_tmp] - '0') + r;

    if (tmp > 9) {
        digit = tmp % 10;
        c[i] = digit + '0';
        r = 1;
    }
    else {
        r = 0;
        c[i] = tmp + '0';
    }
    a_tmp--;
    b_tmp--;
  }
}

int main() {
    int T;
    char a[n];
    char b[n];
    char c[n];
    do {
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        summ(a, b, c);
        for (int i = strlen(c) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            cout << c[i];
       }
        cout << "\nПродолжить - 1, закончить - 0." << endl;
        cin >> T;

    } while (T == 1);
}
```

С целыми положительными цифрами все работает, но есть проблема, в моем задании мне нужно, чтобы функция считала еще и сумму отрицательных чисел, также записывая их в массив, например, пользователь вводит 34 и -11, функция должна посчитать ответ = 23.

Помогите, пожалуйста, уже неделю мучаюсь с этим заданием, а в голову так и не приходит как это реализовать..

Comment: т.е. вам надо реализовать по сути сложение в столбик чисел представленных в виде строк?

Comment: да, именно, но здесь не совсем длинная арифметика, как мне объяснили, решение должно быть проще

Comment: ну это и есть длинная арифметика - может имелось в виду, что числа от -128 до 127 и тогда их полностью в char можно хранить - может это имелось в виду?

Comment: максимальных размер массива, который может заполнить пользователь - char[100]

Comment: ну т.е. все таки длинная арифметика, но при этом конечная, ок, а что мешает написать функцию вычитания тогда и сводить сложение положительного и отрицательного чисел просто к вычитанию положительных?

Comment: Эта задача как-то отличается от [предыдущей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1201509/176064)?

Answer (score 0):

Ну все тривиально - дам пример на строке (ввод организуйте сами)

Алгоритм такой :

1. разбиваем строку на токены
2. парсим токены на числа (мало ли кто то введет бяку) и дампим в вектор
3. делаем акум

Остальное обернете сами)

вот пример кода

ВАЖНО: максимальное число обусловлено лимитом std::stoi +-2,147,483,647

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> SeparateLineToWordsByRegexp(std::string line) {
  std::regex words_regex("[^\\s,;]+");
  auto words_begin =
      std::sregex_iterator(std::begin(line), std::end(line), words_regex);
  auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();
  std::vector<std::string> words;
  for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
    words.push_back((*i).str());
  }

  return words;
}

std::vector<int64_t> PickIntsFromStringVector(std::vector<std::string> words) {
  std::vector<int64_t> ret;
  for (const auto &word : words) {
    if (word.find_first_not_of("-0123456789.") == std::string::npos) {
      ret.push_back(std::stoi(word));
    }
  }

  return ret;
}

int main() {
  std::string line{"1 2 3 4   11 19"};
  auto words{SeparateLineToWordsByRegexp(line)};
  auto dig_vector{PickIntsFromStringVector(words)};
  auto ret{std::accumulate(std::begin(dig_vector), std::end(dig_vector), 0)};
  std::cout << "ret is : " << ret << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А какую задачу вы тут решали?

Comment: @vp_arth  <<Написать функцию на языке C++, которая считает сумму чисел, когда пользователь вводит их с клавиатуры.>> Тз из задания автора. токо без ввода

Comment: Не думаю, что это сработает с числами порядка 1e100

Comment: @vp_arth будет заказ на такие числа - сделаем. тут лимит обозначен stoi - 2,147,483,647 , Если вы хотите больште числа - то есть boost

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1203679/%d0%a1-%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-char/1203699?noredirect=1#comment2101745_1203679

Answer (score 0):

Всего существуют 4 ситуации с учетом `+` и `-` их можно разделить на два типа:

1. сложение:  `-a + -b` и `a + b`
2. вычитание: `a + -b` и `-a + b`

Поэтому код можно унифицировать работая с числами по `|модулю|` инвертировав результат при необходимости получить отрицательное значение:

1. `a < 0 && b < 0` тогда `a + b` отрицательное число
2. `|a| > |b| && a < 0` или `|a| < |b| && b < 0` тогда `a + b` отрицательное число

Что касается переносимого отстатка, то он считается по разному в зависимости от того складываем ли мы либо отнимаем:

1. при сложении  либо `0` либо `1`
2. при вычитании либо `0` либо `-1`

Для `правильного` вычитания мы должны его производить из большего по модулю, поэтому я добавил функцию `is_a_gt_or_equal_b` которая определяет какое из чисел больше сравнвая их строчные представления (`-`  тоже учитывается, но данном случае в нем нет необходимости так как передаются аргументы по модулю)

Одним из интересных моментов был момент когда я получал:

- вместо `9` символ `/`
- вместо `1` символ `'`

Не долго думая я понял что это смещение от `'0'` влево чего быть не должно, поэтому я прибавлял `10` для того чтобы:

- смещение из `-9` стало `1`
- смещение из `-1` стало `9`

C учетом того что я заполняю результирующую строку с конца а не с начала, мне нет необходимости делать `цикл` для вывода числа достаточно лишь обрезать буфер до нужной длины, это делает функция `get_tail` она же убирает из числа ведущие нули если они вдруг появились:

- `123` + `-100` = `023`

Чтобы не гонять лишний раз циклы я делаю сравнение чисел в самом начале не дадут ли они `0` логика простая (возможно можно проще):

- `'-'` + `a` == `b`
- `'-'` + `b` == `a`

В ходе написания кода мне очень помогли тесты, для краткости я их не включил в этот код. Но я оставил некоторые комментарии в основном ввиде выражений чтобы было понятна цель проверки или условия.

Если будут предложения по оптимизации кода с удовольствием почитаю (давно не писал на плюсах). Если возникнут вопросы на которые я не ответил выше, так же готов ответить.

**полный код:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

const int n = 100;

inline int get_digit( char c ) { return c - '0'; }

inline bool is_negative( char * c ){ return c[0] == '-'; }

inline void get_abs( char * c, char * h ){
  sprintf( h, &c[is_negative( c )? 1 : 0], strlen(c) );
}

inline void get_neg( char * c, char * h ){
  sprintf( h, "-%s", &c[is_negative( c ) ? 1 : 0] );
}

inline void set_neg( char * c ){
  char t[n];
  get_abs( c, t );
  get_neg( t, c );
}

bool is_sum_zero ( char  * a, char * b ){
  string tempA = a;
  string tempB = b;
  return '-' + tempA == tempB 
      || '-' + tempB == tempA;
}

void get_tail( char* c, int size ){
  int len = strlen( c );
  memcpy( c, c + (len-size) , size + 1 );
  int i = 0; // убираем ведущие нули
  while( c[i]=='0' && i < n - 1 ){ i++; }
  if (i){ memcpy(c, c + i , size + 1 - i); }
}

bool is_a_gt_or_equal_b( char *a, char *b ){
  int  len_a = strlen( a ), 
       len_b = strlen( b );
  bool bNeg  = is_negative( b ),
       aNeg  = is_negative( a );
  if ( len_a > len_b  && !aNeg ) return true; //  10000 > -10   || 100000 > 10 
  if ( len_a < len_b  && bNeg ) return true;  //  -10 > -10000   || 10 > -10000 
  if ( len_a > len_b  && ( !bNeg && !aNeg ) ) return true;  //  1 > 10000
  if ( len_a < len_b  && ( !bNeg && !aNeg ) ) return false;  //  -1 > -10000 

  int i = aNeg ? 1 : 0;
  while( i != len_a ){
    if ( get_digit( a[i] ) != get_digit( b[i] ) ){
      return get_digit( a[i] ) >= get_digit( b[i] ) ? !aNeg : aNeg;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return true;
}

int exract_digit( char *c, int &pos ){
  if (pos >= 0) {
    int d = get_digit( c[pos--] );
    return d;
  }
  return 0;
}

void summ( char* a, char* b, char* c ){
  enum {POSPOS, NEGPOS, POSNEG, NEGNEG};
  
  if (is_sum_zero( a, b )){ // a + b = 0
    sprintf(c, "%d", 0);
    return;
  }

  char mod_a[n],
       mod_b[n];

  get_abs(a, mod_a);
  get_abs(b, mod_b);

  bool bNeg  = is_negative( b ),
       aNeg  = is_negative( a );
  int  c_len = strlen( c ),
       a_tmp = strlen( mod_a ) - 1,
       b_tmp = strlen( mod_b ) - 1,
       tmp   = c_len - 1,
       r     = 0,
       digitA = 0,
       digitB = 0,
       cs = (bNeg * 2 + aNeg);

  switch( cs ){
    case POSPOS:  // ++
    case NEGNEG:  // --
      while ( a_tmp > -1 || b_tmp > -1 || r ){
        digitA = exract_digit( mod_a, a_tmp );
        digitB = exract_digit( mod_b, b_tmp );
        int sm = digitA + digitB + r;
        r = sm >= 10 ? 1 : 0;
        c[tmp] = (sm % 10) + '0'; 
        tmp--; 
      }
      get_tail( c, (c_len-tmp) - 1 );  
      if ( cs == NEGNEG ){ // --
        set_neg( c );
      }
      return;
      break;
    case NEGPOS:  // -+
    case POSNEG:  // +-
      bool isAgtB = is_a_gt_or_equal_b( mod_a, mod_b );
      while ( a_tmp > -1 || b_tmp > -1 || r ){
        digitA = exract_digit( mod_a, a_tmp );
        digitB = exract_digit( mod_b, b_tmp );
        int sm = ( isAgtB ? ( digitA - digitB ) : ( digitB - digitA ) ) + r;
        r = sm < 0 ? -1 : 0;
        if ( sm < 0 ) sm += 10;  // ' --> 1  &&  / --> 9
        c[tmp] = ( sm % 10 ) + '0'; 
        tmp--; 
      }
      get_tail( c, c_len - tmp - 1);  
      if ( !isAgtB && cs != NEGPOS || isAgtB && cs == NEGPOS ){ // 7 - 9  || -9 + 7
        set_neg( c );
      }
      return;
      break;
  }
}

bool is_number(char * c){
  int len = strlen(c);
  bool is_neg = is_negative(c);
  for( int i = is_neg ? 1 : 0; i < len; ++i ){
    if( !( c[i] >= '0' && c[i] <= '9') ){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

int main() {
  int T;
  char a[n];
  char b[n];
  char c[n];
  do {
    cout << "a:";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b:";
    cin >> b;
    if(is_number(a) && is_number(b)){
      summ(a, b, c);
      cout << "Результат:" << c << endl;
    } else {
      cout << "Введите два числа" << endl;
      T = 1;
      continue;
    }
    cout << "\nПродолжить - 1, закончить - 0." << endl;
    cin >> T;
  } while (T == 1);
}
```